# how to config text default color in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I can set the `background-color` to blue:

```
eventHandler.addEventHandler('instanceReady', function(e) {
    e.editor.document.getBody().setStyle('background-color', 'blue');
});
```

How do I change the default color to white in ckeditor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, using that method it would simply be

```
e.editor.document.getBody().setStyle('color', 'white');
```

However, there is a content stylesheet you can also change. It is usually located in your CKEditor installation folder, something like `/ckeditor/contents.css`.

Both of these edit the editor contents only within the editor, the styles don't apply after saving when the editor contents is shown elsewhere. To style the contents there, you need to either parse the CSS manually to be included with your own stylesheet or if the stylings are simple just do them inline. Your output code for the simple styles might look like this (JSP).

```
<div id="CKEditorOutput" style="color:white; background-color:blue;">
<%!
    String ckeOutput() {
        // Here output your saved contents from where ever you saved them
        return "<p>Your CKEditor contents</p>";
    }
%>
<% ckeOutput(); %>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. The input words look 'white'. but i store them , i find it is black in dead. i would display them other place later.

Comment: editing the content.css is the best way for a change like this if you ask me.

Comment: Thanks for all replies. and  it's very kind of you  Nenotlep , i understand what do you mean by your second reply, thanks.